# How to apply Dirichlet boundary condition for lowest order Nedelec element over tetrahedral domain?

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, electromagnetism

The Dirichlet boundary condition is $n \times \vec{E} = n \times \vec{g}$. I don't know how to calculate the boundary value. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! What *do* you know? You do not give us enough detail to give you a useful answer.

Comment: In the Nedelec elements, the tangential component of field (in your case Electric field) is the unknown. Since $n \times E$ is tangent to the surface, that can be projected on to the edges of the tetrahedral element.